# PHP cURL: timeout for specific SSL page (RSS stream)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, timeout, rss

I read RSS streams in a PHP script with cURL. For one page I have the situation that on my localhost (xampp, Windows 10) it works, however my web server gets a timeout. It worked a while ago, something changed either on my web server or on the RSS page.

Any idea what the reason for this could be?

Here is a little test script which causes the timeout on my server and is working on localhost

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.proasyl.de/news/feed/";
    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
if ($content == false || $content == "") {
    echo curl_error($ch)." --- ".curl_errno($ch);
} else {
    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, even with consecutive requests. Just a thought that it may be possible that your server's IP got black listed. https://www.tehplayground.com/oQiPAH32tnRACzS9

Comment: is there a way to check whether the providing server is blacklisting my server?